# Trying to change the id of an element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the id of a div whenever I hover over a selection in my navbar. I just can't see where my problem is. When I inspect the page and hover over the navbar selections, the div id is not changing.

This is my javascript:

```
// Run JS after contents are loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialiseWebPage);


function initialiseWebPage() //Loads DOM content
{
  var navImage = document.getElementById("picture");

  // Variables for each Nav Selection
  const home = document.getElementById("Home");
  const portfolio = document.getElementsById("Portfolio");
  const services = document.getElementsById("Services");
  const achievements = document.getElementsById("Achievements");
  const hobbies = document.getElementsById("Hobbies");

// Event listeners
home.addEventListener("mouseover", changeIdHome);
portfolio.addEventListener("mouseover", changeIdPortfolio);
services.addEventListener("click", changeIdServices);
achievements.addEventListener("mouseover", changeIdAchievements);
hobbies.addEventListener("mouseover", changeIdHobbies);


function changeIdHome()
{
  navImag.id = "Home";
}

function changeIdPortfolio()
{
  navImage.id = "Portfolio";
}

function changeIdServices()
{
  navImage.id = "Services";
}

function changeIdAchievements()
{
  navImage.id = "Achievements";
}

function changeIdHobbies()
{
  navImage.id = "Hobbies";
}

}
```

---

This is the beginning of my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
    <script src="Script.js"></script> <!-- Link document to javascript file -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://m.w3newbie.com/you-tube.css">
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="picture">
```

---

I am pretty sure I linked my js correctly to my html.

as you can see at the bottom of the HTML, the div that im trying to play around has the id of "picture".

Comment: Oh man, the perks of coding :D. Thank you guys, turns out it was the extra 's' in getElement(s)ById. I didn't even notice it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't 100% confirm this, however, on many of your constants you used `document.getElementsById` and it's supposed to be `document.getElementById`.

Heres the changed JavaScript code

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialiseWebPage);


function initialiseWebPage() //Loads DOM content
{
  var navImage = document.getElementById("picture");

  // Variables for each Nav Selection
  const home = document.getElementById("Home");
  const portfolio = document.getElementById("Portfolio");
  const services = document.getElementById("Services");
  const achievements = document.getElementById("Achievements");
  const hobbies = document.getElementById("Hobbies");

// Event listeners
home.addEventListener("mouseover", changeIdHome);
portfolio.addEventListener("mouseover", changeIdPortfolio);
services.addEventListener("click", changeIdServices);
achievements.addEventListener("mouseover", changeIdAchievements);
hobbies.addEventListener("mouseover", changeIdHobbies);


function changeIdHome()
{
  navImag.id = "Home";
}

function changeIdPortfolio()
{
  navImage.id = "Portfolio";
}

function changeIdServices()
{
  navImage.id = "Services";
}

function changeIdAchievements()
{
  navImage.id = "Achievements";
}

function changeIdHobbies()
{
  navImage.id = "Hobbies";
}

}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Every element should have unique id.

You can't get array from one element:

```
document.getElementsById()
```

So just replace it with:

```
document.getElementById()
```